# Swift code error on setSampleBufferDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors

I am getting an error in the second line, I could not solve it at all.

```
videoDataOutputQueue = dispatch_queue_create("VideoDataOutputQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
videoDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: videoDataOutputQueue)
```

> Error: cannot invoke 'setSampleBufferDelegate' with an argument list
>   of type '(ViewController, queue: dispatch_queue_t)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature for [`setSampleBufferDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoDataOutput_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVCaptureVideoDataOutput/setSampleBufferDelegate:queue:) is

```
func setSampleBufferDelegate(_ sampleBufferDelegate: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate!, queue sampleBufferCallbackQueue: dispatch_queue_t!)
```

In particular the first parameter needs to be a [`AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate). Your class `ViewController` is apparently not such a delegate. You can fix that by conforming your class to it:

```
class ViewController : YourPreviousInheritances, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate { 
    ...
}
```